# Geometrically Impossible Spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, causality

A result in math says that $S^n$ carries a Lorentzian metric iff $n$ is odd.

Using it we can observe that a 2-sphere spacetime is impossible, a 3-sphere spacetime is geometrically possible, but again a 4-sphere spacetime is impossible, and so on.

Are there resources in the literature that deal with geometrically impossible spacetime or offering a general result to be used and checked?

Comment: Are you looking for other impossibility proofs?

Comment: Looks like there is a result which says on non-compact maniforld Lorentzian metric is possible, and on compact iff the Euler characteristic is zero, are there any more relatd results? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44861/for-which-b-it-is-possible-that-sn-can-have-a-lorentz-metric-why/47446#47446